# Shadow inside custom views causes flickering

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom popup view in my iOS application and inside that there are two views who need a small shadow below them. I'm animating this popup from the bottom to the top of the screen. While animating it flickers/stutters because of the shadows. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Here is the code that I'm using for the shadows (Swift 3):

```
view.layer.masksToBounds = false
view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
view.layer.shadowRadius = 1
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
```

And yes, it is definitely because of the shadows.

Comment: Can you paste the animation code here?

Comment: I'm not at my computer atm. But I can tell you that I'm using the centerY constraint of my square popup to animate with UIView.animate(...). I'll add the code to my question when I'm back at the computer.